# Join tables with two conditions or two columns in common in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, multiple-conditions

I have two tables. Table 1 has item, color, and size for all items in the store. Table 2 is a pricing list and has item, size, price, and itemid. Price is determined from item and size. How can I get the price on to Table 1?

Table1- Example

| item | color | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shirt | red | M |
| pants | blue | S |

...

Table2- Example

| item | size | price | item_size_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shirt | S | 2.99 | 013443 |
| shirt | M | 3.99 | 013444 |
| shirt | L | 4.99 | 013445 |
| pants | S | 5.99 | 013452 |

...

Result wanted:

| item | color | size | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shirt | red | M | 3.99 |
| pants | blue | S | 5.99 |

...

I have tried:

```
SELECT item, color, size, price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.item = table2.item AND table1.size = table2.size
```

But this results in all nulls for price.

I have tried CASE WHEN statements and while this worked, it took forever so is there is a better way?

Comment: Maybe the matching rows are not found because there are leading/trailing spaces in `item` and/or `size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct, except that columns of the same name exist in both tables and you have not specified which one you are referring to.
See dbFiddle line below for schema and testing.

```
 /* query provided in the question as provided */
SELECT item, color, size, price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.item = table2.item AND table1.size = table2.size
```

```
ERROR:  column reference "item" is ambiguous
LINE 2: SELECT item, color, size, price
               ^
```

```
/* query provided with table identifiers added */
SELECT table1.item, table1.color, table1.size, table2.price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.item = table2.item AND table1.size = table2.size
```

```
item  | color | size | price
:---- | :---- | :--- | ----:
pants | blue  | S    |  5.99
shirt | red   | M    |  3.99
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=980abf263302913977adfa16ce12d7ea)*

Comment: Double check that the values in the columns match exactly? Upper/Lower case, spaces/puncuation. Are the columns the same type? If the columns are type CHAR try with a `LIKE` instead of `=` ?

Comment: that was my issue. I had one case wrong and it messed it all up. Thank you.